# Paperclip svg image uploading stalled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, paperclip

I have a relationship where a user can have many designs.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  le
has_many :designs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :designs
```

Design model:

```
class Design < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :design, 
:styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
:default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png" , 
 :storage => :dropbox,
:dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
:dropbox_options => {environment: ENV["RACK_ENV"]}
belongs_to :user
end
```

Design controller.

```
def create        
if current_user.designs.create(design_params)
  flash[:alert] = "Successfully created the design."
  redirect_to designer_show_path  
else 
  render designer_create_path
end
end

def new
   @design = current_user.designs.build
end
```

Now everything works fine except after I upload an image, it seems to go on forever for a svg file even less than 10k. But for other image formats it works just fine.